# How to convert a string to camel case in phpstorms (velocity based) file tempates?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, phpstorm, velocity

What I've tried so far is:

```
## $NAME is something like 'my_controller_c'
#set($NAME = $NAME.removeAndHump($NAME))
#set($NAME = $NAME.underscoresToCamelCase(String)
```

But that does not work. The first one does nothing, the second one throws an java error.

I also tried using regular expressions and to loop through the string, but my java knowledge is very basic.

Comment: 1) You cannot redefine `#NAME` -- you have to assign the value of it to a local variable and then work with it (e.g. `#set($class = ${NAME})`) 2) I've no clue what methods are available there .. but Java's own methods for `String` class do work: `#set($class = $class.toUpperCase())` 3) If there is no built-in function to do what you want -- maybe try "sort-of" creating your own: Velocity supports loops -- try them (to split `foo_bar` into `foo` and `bar`; upper case first letter and join back as `FooBar` (just an idea -- not a Velocity user at all)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is, what I ended up doing:

```
#set($ctrlName = $NAME.replaceAll("-c$", ""))
#set($ctrlNewName = "")
#foreach($str in $ctrlName.split("-"))
  #set($str = $str.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+$str.substring(1))
  #set($ctrlNewName = $ctrlNewName + $str)
#end
#set ( $ctrlNewName = $ctrlNewName + "Ctrl" )
```

Answer (score 13):

The following works in PhpStorm 9 (and probably all of the other JetBrains IDEs, I would guess):

```
#set($new_name = ${StringUtils.removeAndHump(${NAME}, "-")})

class $new_name {
}
```